# RSS/Atom parsing library for .Net

Tags: .net, parsing, rss, atom-feed

I'm trying to find a library that can read a given RSS/Atom feed, and that can guess its format and abstract it as a list of items.

The idea is to build a simple RSS reader that could take any feed.

I know PHP has a few libraries doing just that, but I can't find any .Net version.

Comment: I struggled to get Atom.NET working productively, maybe that was just me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [ASP.NET RSS Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit) does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this one first :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using 3.5 you can use classes from the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace

Comment: I had no idea this existed, but it does exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Argotic](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) is a pretty comprehensive content syndication framework.

Comment: It looks impressive, do you know why RSS Toolkit is much more popular? Is it only because he was the first?